# does the submit button have to be contained in the form

Tags: javascript, html

I want my submit button to be positioned somewhere that outside my form element? Do I have any options? With the exception of jquery.

Thanks,
rodchar

Comment: When you say jQuery, do you also mean Javascript?

Comment: If you could do that, what would the behaviour of pages with multiple forms be?

Comment: Since your `<form>` could take in the whole page, are you asking because you have multiple forms on the page?

Comment: @All comments: Sorry I wasn't more clear, please disregard my exceptions in OP (as it caused confusion for myself as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common situation. I think this will do it (haven't tested it):

```
<form id="form1" action="someAction.cgi" method="GET">
    <!-- other fields go here -->
</form>
<form id="form2" action="someOtherAction.cgi" method="GET">
    <!-- other fields go here -->
</form>

<form>
    <input value="Form One" type="button"
        onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();"/>
    <input value="Form Two" type="button"
        onclick="document.getElementById('form2').submit();"/>
</form>
```

I'm not sure if you need that last `<form>`. I seem to remember browsers ignoring events if the button wasn't in a `form`.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach to this is merely to set the [`form` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/forms.html#attr-fae-form) on the button:

```
<form id="first">
    <input type="submit" form="second" value="Submit Second" />
</form>
<form id="second">
    <input type="submit" form="first" value="Submit First" />
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52wgc2ym/

---

**Original Answer**

The natural behavior of a submit button is to submit the nearest form up its hierarchy. The only other way to get a button to submit a form which it doesn't reside in is to use JavaScript (which is what jQuery is, basically).

If necessary, you could reposition the submit button so that it *appears* as though it's not in the form visually when the page is rendered. You would do this using CSS, which may give the desired result(s).

Comment: "javascript (which is what jQuery is, basically)"...hmmm

Comment: jQuery is a library; JavaScript is a language. Somebody may be open to using JavaScript, but [not] open to using a particular library.

Comment: this is the modern HTML5 answer, and should be moved to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

The submit button needs to be inside the form, yes.

It seems strange to me to want it any other way, anyway. What would be the point if the input controls were in one place on the page, and the submit button was *waaay* over there somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, structurally the submit button needs to be inside a form element for the document to be valid X/HTML. But visually you can position the submit button anywhere you want with appropriate CSS (float, absolute/relative positioning, etc). You could also write JavaScript that will trigger the form submission and tie it to another element.

Comment: May you elaborate on this and name any source? I can't find where it says that button tag needs to be inside a form tag. In contrary I found i.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button where it says "If your buttons are not for submitting form data to a server, be sure to set their type attribute to button." and "form: This attribute lets you associate <button> elements to <form>s anywhere in the document, not just inside a <form>".

Answer (score 2):

Inputs of type `submit` only make sense as children of `<form>` elements. But using CSS I'm sure you can position it wherever you like. Remember form elements are "invisible" so just expand the tags around more of your content and you're covered. Here's [the documentation on forms for HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.1), it's still appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the another type of answer getting more clear view from egrunin answer

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="someAction.cgi" method="GET">
        <!-- other fields go here -->
    </form>
    <form id="form2" name="form2" action="someOtherAction.cgi" method="GET">
        <!-- other fields go here -->
    </form>

    Calling by form id:
    <form>
        <input value="Form One" type="button"
            onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();"/>
        <input value="Form Two" type="button"
            onclick="document.getElementById('form2').submit();"/>
    </form>

or Calling by form name:

    <form>
        <input value="Form One" type="button"
            onclick="document.form1.submit();"/>
        <input value="Form Two" type="button"
            onclick="document.form2.submit();"/>
    </form>
```